# Filter links with the help of text input search and hide non matching

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, filter, show-hide

i got a problem i am not very familar with jquery effects and functions.
I wanted a simple filter function where you can filter links which are categories on a page in different but same build containers.
Code Follows:

The Html Containers with the links which i want to filter and set to display none if dont match:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 py-4">
   <h4 class="text-white" id="hideOnFilter">Generatoren und Bilderupload</h4>
   <nav class="nav flex-column" id="filterholder">
      <a class="nav-link text-white catlink" href="#" title="Cat 1 description" id="filterelement">Cat 1</a>
      <a class="nav-link text-white catlink" href="#" title="Cat 2 description" id="filterelement">Cat 2</a>
      <a class="nav-link text-white catlink" href="#" title="Cat 3 description" id="filterelement">Cat 3</a>
      <a class="nav-link text-white catlink" href="#" title="Cat 4 description" id="filterelement">Cat 4</a>        
   </nav>
</div>
```

These containers above are placed six times on page but always the same class id and structure.

The JQuery Part to filter the links i wrote since so far:

```
 $('.search').keyup(function(){
          var searchcatquery = $(this).val();
          //alert(searchcatquery); 
          //Filter and hide links which dont match to search input? 
          return false;
 });
```

Comment: Either don't keep any `id` for an element or keep distinctive `id` for every element on an HTML page. `id`s should not be duplicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach using [jquery filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
   $('.search').keyup(function(){
      var searchcatquery = $(this).val().toLowerCase(); //convert to lowercase     

      $(".catlink").show().filter(function(){
         return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf( searchcatquery ) == -1 //filter all those who doesn't have searchcatquery as substring
      }).hide(); //hide filtered values

      return false;
    });
```

**Note**

- Either don't keep any `id` for an element or keep distinctive `id` for every element on an HTML page. `id`s should not be duplicated.
- Logic given above doesn't use `id` attribute for filtering.

Comment: Rhx a lot helps ma but how to make it not so sensitive about uppercase letters. what i mean is that it should be not reasonable if the letter a is uppercase or lowercase?

Comment: @PhilHedtmann Check the updates. You need to convert both values which are being compared to lowercase.